# Reference-request: Inequalities

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a book that deals with inequalities like

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} < 1 -  \frac{x}{ \pi} \qquad x \in (0,\pi)$$

perhaps some geometric exposition. I have heard that Hardy's book is good, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book you might like is: **Intro to geometric inequalities by Mitrinovic** Kluwer Academic Press.

Answer (score 0):

Hardy, Little, and Polya is a classic.

Introduction to Inequalities: Edwin F. Beckenbach, R. Bellman.